# How to create a Spring Specification object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications

Using `tkaczmarzyk arg-resolver library` [see here](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver)
with my Spring Boot/Hibernate project
I want to search into my database.

The entity:

```
public class Animal { 
    private String color;
    private String name;
    ... 
}
```

The repository class:

```
public inteface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Animal> {
}
```

I created a new interface that extends `Specification`:

```
@And({
@Spec(params = "color", spec = Equal.class),
@Spec(params = "name", spec = Equal.class)
})

public interface AnimalSearch extends Specification<Animal> {
}
```

Now i want in some method to do something like this:

```
public void myMethod() {

    AnimalSearch search; /* here is my question. How can I create some kind of object with 2 parameters: color and name for the interface?*/

    Collection<Animal> animalsFiltered = animalRepository.findAll(search);

    // etc
}
```

Do I need to create, let's say, a class like this:

```
public class AnimalSearchObject implements AnimalSearch {
private String color;
private String name;
...
}
```

and have:

```
AnimalSearchObject search = new AnimalSearchObject("my_color", "my_name");
Collection<Animal> animalsFiltered = animalRepository.findAll(search);
```

or is there a easier way?

Comment: Did you try the specification of Spring boot itself? You can work with them without aditional libs.

Comment: it's the standard library we use in this project. I should use it here, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **CAN'T** do this.`tkaczmarzyk arg-resolver library` is helpful to only mapping parameters received in the request. What I asked cannot be done using this library